# How to reset the list of authors

Tags: titles, authblk

I'm trying to put a few articles together into a small publication. Each article has been sent to me in `.tex` format, so I want to include them into one file, for the whole publication.
My code is something like this:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{newclude}
    \usepackage{docmute,subfiles}
    \begin{document}
    \input{article1}
    \newpage
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \input{article2}
    \end{document}
```

Each article uses authblk package, so in article1, I have:

```
    \author[1]{A}
    \author[2]{B}
    \affil[1]{AffilA}
    \affil[2]{AffilB}
```

And in article2:

```
    \author[1]{C}
    \affil[1]{AffilC}
```

The problem is that including the files as above, the `authblk` package adds all the the authors, so after compilation, all authors (A,B and C) appears in the `\maketitle` of article2. I guess I need to reset the author list, but I can't find out how. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

I see you already found part of the solution, but you also need to decrement the author counter to avoid the preceding comma in front of the authorlist:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\AB@affillist}{}
\renewcommand{\AB@authlist}{}
\setcounter{authors}{0}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We prefer to post complete examples instead of fragments of code

Comment: This is not working for me..@matmo

Comment: Kindly look into this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401081/how-to-reset-the-author-list?noredirect=1&lq=1  @ChristianHupfer

Comment: @David: I am no bibliography - expert.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That question is related to `authblk` package when using multiple titles in`book` or `article` class. I am in a position to make the report on it where i have more than 100 abstracts. Kindly help (you may suggest some person to help).