# How to reset author list using authblk

Tags: authblk

I recently posted a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176954/how-to-reset-the-list-of-authors) that is still unanswered. I'm trying to put several articles into a publication. In each article the authorlist is defined using authblk. So I have:

Article 1:

```
\begin{document}
\title{title1}
\author[*]{First}
\author[**]{Second}
\affil[*]{FirstAffil}
\affil[**]{SecondAffil}
\maketitle
Text
\end{document}
```

Article 2:

```
\begin{document}
\title{title2}
\author[*]{Third}
\affil[*]{ThirdAffil}
\maketitle
Text
\end{document}
```

Main file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}
\subimport{Folder1/}{article1}
\subimport{Folder2/}{article2}
\end{document}
```

My problem was that with the second `\maketitle` (the one corresponding to article 2), ALL the authors appeared.

I solved this problem inserting the following code between the two `\subimport`commands:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\AB@authlist}{}
\renewcommand{\AB@affilist}{}
\makeatother
```

In this way the list of authors is reseted.

However, now in the second article the author is PRECEEDED by a comma, so I get something like this:

title1

First* and Second**

*FirstAffil

**Second Affil

Text

title2

, Third*

*ThirdAfiil

Text

I guess that there is some counter associated with the author list that is not reseted, so `\maketitle` assumes  that the Third author is in fact the third, and not the first one.

Does someone know how can reset this counter (if it exists) or how can I solve this problem anyway?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Instead of reposting your question, you should edit the original one to include a complete mimimal document that shows the problem. This includes samples of the included documents.  Neither this question nor your original question does that (even though the first question is actually closer). Then you might get some help on the question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I edited this last post including a minimal working example.

Comment: @pepe This is an improvement over the previous version of your question, but your example doesn't compile as given. Neither of your imported files have preambles yet they have `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Do you intend them to have preambles etc. (in which case you need some other package to strip that away upon import) or are then intended just to have the material between the `\begin` and `\end{document}`? If you intend the latter, the code still doesn't compile to the result you describe. Please make the example match your problem exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tested my example and indeed it doesn't compile as expected. First,