# How to reset the author list?

Tags: authblk, titling

I am using `titling` package and `authblk` to manage multiple articles in a single file. Below is the code for example

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,dsfont,amssymb,csquotes}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    headheight=4ex,
    includehead,
    includefoot
}

\geometry{
    %   paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    paperheight=25cm,paperwidth=18cm,
    inner=1cm, % Inner margin
    outer=2cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=1cm, % Binding offset
    top=1cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1cm, % Bottom margin
    %   showframe,% show how the type block is set on the page
}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\receivedon[1]{\renewcommand\@receivedon{#1}}
\newcommand\@receivedon{}
\newcommand\acceptedon[1]{\renewcommand\@acceptedon{\underline{\hspace{1.7cm}}#1}}
\newcommand\@acceptedon{}
\newcommand\uniqueid[1]{\renewcommand\@uniqueid{\text{#1}}}
\newcommand\@uniqueid{}
\newcommand\category[1]{\renewcommand\@category{\text{#1}}}
\newcommand\@category{}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-5cm}

\def\@maketitle{%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        %       \raggedright
        $\begin{array}{lcl}
        \text{Unique Id} & :& \@uniqueid  \\
        \text{Category} & : & \@category  \\
        \end{array} $
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \raggedleft
        Received on : \@receivedon \\
        Accepted on : \@acceptedon
    \end{minipage}
    \vskip 1.5em%
    \begin{center}%
        \let \footnote \thanks
        {\LARGE \@title \par}%
        \vskip 1.5em%
        {\large
            \lineskip .5em%
            \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
                \@author 
            \end{tabular}\par}%
        \vskip 1em%
        %{\large \@date}%
    \end{center}%
    \par    
    \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%---------First Article-------------

\title{First Article}


\author[]{Author A}

\affil[]{Affiliation of Author A}

\uniqueid {17ICLAA034} \category{Invited Speaker }
\receivedon{26.09.2017}  \acceptedon{}


\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
    Abstract goes here...
 \end{abstract}


%%%%%%%---------Second Article-------------

\title{Second Article}

\author[]{\underline{Author B}}

\affil[]{Affiliation of author B. }

\uniqueid {17ICLAA087} \category{Invited Speaker }
\receivedon{03.10.2017}  \acceptedon{}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    Abstract goes here...
\end{abstract}




\end{document}
```

### What I want?

- Need to reset the authors list for each article.
- Have to remove the pagebreaks.
- Need to add the title and authors in the table of contents.
- Need to add the authors in the header.

Current output:

[image]

PS: The solution given in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176954/how-to-reset-the-list-of-authors) was not working for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll have a look later. But to repeat myself: you are not using the package.

Comment: oh!!!! I will try to resolve myself and if i succeed i will surely add as an answer or comment here...@Johannes_B

Comment: Are you relyig on the features of the `authblk` package?

Comment: `authblk` is an aged package with no updates for more than a decade. This doesn't mean it is deprecated or outdated, but perhaps there are alternatives? Besides that, `openany` is no useful option for `article` and `\def\@authors{}` will reset the author list

Comment: @Johannes_B Not really. I am looking for a solution which solves my issue. Any solution is fine.

Comment: The most simple solution would be not to use the package, becaue it save the author list.

Comment: Add authors to the header was most likely answered in the other questions. Getting the authors and titles to the table of contents is a completely different question and should be asked as one. It might be even a duplicate. And how it should look like is another unknown, so new question for that please.

Comment: Currently i have removed the authblk package and manually defined like `\atitle` for `title` and `\aauthor` for authors and put all the authors together with scripts on to give the affiliations. `\aaffil` also defined and formatted. And have solved the first two parts. But I know this is not a good solution. Because if I try to put it in header, it will give the superscripts for the authors who have different affiliations.

Comment: `\newcommand{\atitle}[1]{\needspace{5cm} \begin{center}\bfseries\Large #1 \end{center}}
\newcommand{\aauthor}[1]{\begin{center}\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{\centering\small  #1} \end{center}}
\newcommand{\aaffil}[1]{\begin{center}\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{ \centering\small  #1}\end{center} }`

Comment: @David: `\def\AB@authors{}` for each new included article etc. will reset the author list

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It wasn't working for me..

Comment: @David: 'Not working' is no useful description. I used your file from above and just said `\makeatletter\def\AB@authors{}\makeatother` before `\title{Second Article}` and it worked

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You are right...Its working.. Is there any possibility that I can do this globally. Means, can I use while refining the `maketitile` only?

Comment: @David: Redefining `\maketitle` is not enough, since `\maketitle` is used *after* `\author`, i.e. when the author list is already populated. The easiest way (in my point of view), is to use a modified `\author` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I focused on resetting the author list of `authblk` package.

The list of authors is stored in `\AB@authors` which can be reset manually by defining it to be empty before each new title of an article is used.

Another way is to grab the `\author` definition, use a `\RenewDocumentCommand`  and check whether the number of authors is `0`, then redefine `\AB@authors`, then use the original `\author` inside.

`\@maketitle` sets the `author` and `affil` counter values to `0` at its end.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}



\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    headheight=4ex,
    includehead,
    includefoot
}

\geometry{
    %   paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    paperheight=25cm,paperwidth=18cm,
    inner=1cm, % Inner margin
    outer=2cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=1cm, % Binding offset
    top=1cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1cm, % Bottom margin
    %   showframe,% show how the type block is set on the page
}


\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\@uthorfrom@uthblk\author

\RenewDocumentCommand{\author}{+o+m}{%
  \ifnum0=\value{authors}%
  \def\AB@authors{}%
  \fi
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \@uthorfrom@uthblk[#1]{#2}%
  }{%   
    \@uthorfrom@uthblk{#2}%
  }%
}

\newcommand\receivedon[1]{\renewcommand\@receivedon{#1}}
\newcommand\@receivedon{}
\newcommand\acceptedon[1]{\renewcommand\@acceptedon{\underline{\hspace{1.7cm}}#1}}
\newcommand\@acceptedon{}
\newcommand\uniqueid[1]{\renewcommand\@uniqueid{\text{#1}}}
\newcommand\@uniqueid{}
\newcommand\category[1]{\renewcommand\@category{\text{#1}}}
\newcommand\@category{}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-5cm}



\def\@maketitle{%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    % \raggedright
    $\begin{array}{lcl}
      \text{Unique Id} & :& \@uniqueid  \\
      \text{Category} & : & \@category  \\
    \end{array} $
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \raggedleft
        Received on : \@receivedon \\
        Accepted on : \@acceptedon
      \end{minipage}
    \vskip 1.5em%
    \begin{center}%
      \let \footnote \thanks
      {\LARGE \@title \par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
      {\large
        \lineskip .5em%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
          \@author% 
        \end{tabular}\par}%
        \vskip 1em%
        % {\large \@date}%
      \end{center}%
      \par    
      \vskip 1.5em%
      % reset counters for possible next \author macro
      \setcounter{authors}{0}%
      \setcounter{affil}{0}%
    }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%---------First Article-------------

\title{First Article}


\author[]{Author A}

\affil[]{Affiliation of Author A}

\uniqueid {17ICLAA034} \category{Invited Speaker }
\receivedon{26.09.2017}  \acceptedon{}


\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
  Abstract goes here...
\end{abstract}


%%%%%%%---------Second Article-------------




\title{Second Article}

\author[]{\underline{Author B}}

\affil[]{Affiliation of author B. }

\uniqueid {17ICLAA087} \category{Invited Speaker }
\receivedon{03.10.2017}  \acceptedon{}

\makeatletter
\makeatother
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    Abstract goes here...
\end{abstract}




\end{document}
```