# Is there something like \emptyauthor and \emptyaffil similar to \emptythanks in TeX?

Tags: authblk, titling

I try to implement 2 titles in TeX document using package `titling`.

Something similar was considered in [How to reset the author list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401081/how-to-reset-the-author-list), but this solution works only for 1 author and 1 affiliation for each title. Contrary, I have 2 authors and 2 affilations for each title. As a result of code, I get 4 authors and 4 affiliations for the 2nd title which is not appropriate!

As you can see in WE there is a feature `\emptythanks` in package `titling` which is fine for me and it'll be great to find something like `\emptyauthor` and `\emptyaffil`. But maybe there is an another way to solve this problem ...

Could someone help me?!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}

%\newcommand{\emptyauthor}{\global\let\@author\@empty}
%\newcommand{\emptyaffil}{\global\let\@affil\@empty}


\makeatletter \LetLtxMacro\@uthorfrom@uthblk\author

\RenewDocumentCommand{\author}{+o+m}{%
  \ifnum0=\value{authors}%
  \def\AB@authors{}%
  \fi
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \@uthorfrom@uthblk[#1]{#2}%
  }{%
    \@uthorfrom@uthblk{#2}%
  }%
}

\def\@maketitle{%
    \begin{center}%
      \let \footnote \thanks
      {\LARGE \@title \par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
      {\large
        \lineskip .5em%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
          \@author%
        \end{tabular}\par}%
        \vskip 1em%
        % {\large \@date}%
      \end{center}%
      \par
      \vskip 1.5em%
      % reset counters for possible next \author macro
      \setcounter{authors}{0}%
      \setcounter{affil}{0}%
    }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%---------First Article-------------

\title{First Article\thanks{thanks to everyone.}}


\author[1]{Author A1}
\author[2]{Author A2}

\affil[1]{Affiliation of Author A1}
\affil[2]{Affiliation of Author
A2}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
  Abstract goes here...
\end{abstract}


%%%%%%%---------Second Article-------------


\emptythanks
%\emptyauthor
%\emptyaffil

\title{Second Article\thanks{thanks to your mom.}}

\author[1]{\underline{Author B1}}
\author[2]{\underline{Author B2}}

\affil[1]{Affiliation of Author B1}
\affil[2]{Affiliation of Author
B2}

\makeatletter
\makeatother
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    Abstract goes here...
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to reset the authors and affiliations using the following commands:

```
\renewcommand\AB@authlist{}
\renewcommand\AB@affillist{}
\renewcommand\AB@authors{}
\renewcommand\AB@affilsep{\protect\Affilfont}
\renewcommand\AB@blk@and{\protect\Authfont\protect\AB@setsep}
```

The first three lines are needed to empty the macros that store the authors and affiliations. The last two lines are needed because these macros will be set to something else after the first use. So, if we want to re-use them, we need to reset them to their initial state.

Applying this approach to your example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}

\makeatletter 

\newcommand{\emptyauthoraffil}{
  \renewcommand\AB@authlist{}
  \renewcommand\AB@affillist{}
  \renewcommand\AB@authors{}
  \renewcommand\AB@affilsep{\protect\Affilfont}
  \renewcommand\AB@blk@and{\protect\Authfont\protect\AB@setsep}
}

\LetLtxMacro\@uthorfrom@uthblk\author

\RenewDocumentCommand{\author}{+o+m}{%
  \ifnum0=\value{authors}%
  \def\AB@authors{}%
  \fi
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \@uthorfrom@uthblk[#1]{#2}%
  }{%
    \@uthorfrom@uthblk{#2}%
  }%
}

\def\@maketitle{%
    \begin{center}%
      \let \footnote \thanks
      {\LARGE \@title \par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
      {\large
        \lineskip .5em%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
          \@author%
        \end{tabular}\par}%
        \vskip 1em%
        % {\large \@date}%
      \end{center}%
      \par
      \vskip 1.5em%
      % reset counters for possible next \author macro
      \setcounter{authors}{0}%
      \setcounter{affil}{0}%
    }
    
\makeatother

\begin{document}


%%%%%%%---------First Article-------------

\title{First Article\thanks{thanks to everyone.}}

\author[1]{Author A1}
\author[2]{Author A2}

\affil[1]{Affiliation of Author A1}
\affil[2]{Affiliation of Author
A2}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  Abstract goes here ...
\end{abstract}


%%%%%%%---------Second Article-------------

\emptythanks
\emptyauthoraffil

\title{Second Article\thanks{thanks to your mom.}}

\author[1]{\underline{Author B1}}
\author[2]{\underline{Author B2}}

\affil[1]{Affiliation of Author B1}
\affil[2]{Affiliation of Author
B2}

\makeatletter
\makeatother
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    Abstract goes here ...
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

For the second article, you will then get the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!